# Which OpenLayers highlights should I present to a non-specialist audience?

Tags: openlayers

There is an event in my University that interests in Open Source Software. I am supposed to give a short presentation about anything related so I thought about giving a simple overview about OpenLayers Library.

Would you please give me some highlighted points that really matter non-specialist audience?

Answer (score 1):

The Open Geo site has a good overview at http://opengeo.org/technology/openlayers/

Answer (score 1):

It works with a wide range of base-maps that users are familiar with (Google, Bing, Yahoo, OpenStreetMap) so there is no lock-in to a particular service. In non-technical terms, if Google decide to charge per page view you can just switch to another provider.